# Update a third column for each common row identified by two different columns - R

Tags: r

I want to update the column `Participation_type` (five different values are available) based on common rows identified by two different columns(`custID` and `accntID`). Also i have over 130000 records with around 7000 different combinations of `custID` and `accntID`. I was thinking if i could use random sampling from one of the five participation_type values to populate this variable. But not sure how.

**Also there is no visible pattern for the combination of `custID` and `accntID` (say repetition of the combination of values for `custID` and `accntID`). So I believe vectorization will not work.

Sample data:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(custID = rep(c("a", "b"), times = 2),
                 accntID = rep(c(4, 7), times = 2), 
                 Batch_ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), 
                 Participation_type = character(4))

     custID accntID Batch_ID
      a        4      1
      b        7      1 
      c        8      1
      b        7      2
      a        4      2
      d        4      1
```

Final Data: The output should be as mentioned below.

```
   custID  accntID  Batch_ID Participation_type
    a       4        1                BEN
    b       7        1                 AC
    c       8        1                 RC
    b       7        2                 AC
    a       4        2                BEN
    d       4        1                BEN
```

Thanks a lot for you suggestion and help.

Comment: How do we know the values `BEN', 'AC', "RC' etc.  Is it stored in a separate vector

Comment: Just five values for the participation_type. I can create a vector on the fly or store them in a vector. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We create a key/value dataset and then join with the original dataset to create the 'Participation_type'

Create the key/value dataset based on the unique combinations of 'custID', 'accntID' and the possible values of 'Participation_type'

```
library(data.table)
keyvalDat <- data.table(custID = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                         accntID = c(4, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
                         Participation_type = c("BEN", "AC", "RC", "O", "A"))
```

then join with the original dataset

```
df[keyvalDat, Participation_type := Participation_type, on = .(custID, accntID)]
df
#   custID accntID Batch_ID Participation_type
#1:      a       4        1                BEN
#2:      b       7        1                 AC
#3:      c       8        1                 RC
#4:      a       4        2                BEN
#5:      b       7        2                 AC
```

#### data

```
df <- data.table(custID = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'),
     accntID = c(4, 7, 8, 4, 7), Batch_ID = rep(1:2, c(3, 2)))

v1 <- c("BEN", "AC", "RC")
```

Comment: Thanks but i do not think it will work. My sample data shows a pattern like that but that is not really the case.

Comment: @VikashKumar  Ok, then please update with an example that is representative of the real case

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cannot share the actual data for obvious reasons. I am actually preparing a mock data. So for no reasons, a particular combination of accntID and custID should have a given participation_type value only. Rather they can have any participation_type value from say "AC", "BEN", "RC", "O", "A". But the given combination of custID and accntID across all BatchIDs should have the same participation_type value.

Comment: You don't need to share the actuaal data, but a reprsentative data.  At present your example is giving a direction to uise this method to solvre the issue.  If it is not the case, you may have to update your post with a new logic

Comment: Thanks akrun. Yeah i am thinking on making it more elaborate. The sample data seems to suggest a pattern.

Comment: @VikashKumar  Based on your earlier comments, I updated the post.  It should work now.  Make changes to the keyvalDat as I don't know all the possible combinations in your original data

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun. Somehow was able to figure that out but your code makes it a lot easy  and simple to do.